# Locating column that correspond to a value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a define dataframe

```
+---+----+-------+-------+--------+
|ID |Fear |Happy |Angry  |Excited |              
+---+-----+------+-------+--------+
|   |     |      |       |        |
+---+-----+------+-------+--------+
```

I did emotional analysis on a text using NRCLex.
Let say it returns

```
text_emotion = [Fear, Happy]
```

How do **locate the values in the list and put it to the corresponding columns a 1 if exist and 0 if it doesn't**?

```
+---+----+-------+-------+--------+
|ID |Fear |Happy |Angry  |Excited |              
+---+-----+------+-------+--------+
| A |1    |0     |0      |0       |
+---+-----+------+-------+--------+
```

I tried using **get_dummies**. But then it is not working on my situation given i want it to correspond to the defined dataframe. It gives me this instead:

```
+---+----+-------+
|ID |Fear |Happy |             
+---+-----+------+
| A | 1   | 1    | 
+---+-----+------+
```

I would appreicate any help. Thank You

Comment: Create a dictionary, add that dictionary as a row. Or you can create another list and add that as row as well

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-append-list-as-a-row-to-dataframe/amp/

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Fear", "Angry", "Happy", "Excited"])
mylist = ["Fear", "Happy"]
pattern = '|'.join(mylist)
row = frame.columns.str.contains(pattern).astype(int)
frame.loc[0] = row
```

If you have a whole list you can loop through and append each row to the dataframe using `frame.loc[i]`. Like so:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Fear", "Angry", "Happy", "Excited"])
mylist = frame.columns
mylists = [["Fear", "Happy"], ["Angry", "Excited"]]
for i in range(len(mylists)):
    the_list = mylists[i]
    pattern = '|'.join(the_list)
    row = frame.columns.str.contains(pattern).astype(int)
    frame.loc[i] = row
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you represent your data. Let's say you have the following dataframe constructed from your sentiment analysis results:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':['Fear', 'Happy', 'Emotional'], 
    'B':['Excited', 'Emotional', 'Angry'], 
})
```

Then you could do:

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.T, prefix=['']*len(df.T.columns), prefix_sep='')
out = df_dummies.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

print(out):

```
   Angry  Emotional  Excited  Fear  Happy
A      0          1        0     1      1
B      1          1        1     0      0
```

If you want the index as separate ID then

```
out = out.rename_axis('ID').reset_index()
```

print(out):

```
  ID  Angry  Emotional  Excited  Fear  Happy
0  A      0          1        0     1      1
1  B      1          1        1     0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd never heard of `get_dummies()` before, but here's what I had come up with. It also uses `loc`. It's nice because you could have a predefined or an undefined/empty dataframe and it'll still work.

Since the emotions in `text_emotion` are the same as the dataframe column names, you can just loop through `text_emotion` and make that dataframe row/column value equal to 1 with `loc`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

text_emotion_1 = ['Fear', 'Happy', 'Angry']
text_emotion_2 = ['Happy', 'Excited']

# for row 0, or you can do boolean indexing to assign it
# to the row where index = A
for em in text_emotion_1:
    df.loc[0, em] = 1

# for row 1
for em in text_emotion_2:
    df.loc[1, em] = 1
```

If you started with an empty dataframe, you'd have nulls:

```
   Fear  Happy  Angry  Excited
0   1.0    1.0    1.0      NaN
1   NaN    1.0    NaN      1.0
```

So you could use `fillna()` and `astype()` to replace the nulls with 0's and convert everything to integer, respectively.

```py
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df = df.astype('int')
```

Then your dataframe will look like this (just missing the index column):

```
   Fear  Happy  Angry  Excited
0     1      1      1        0
1     0      1      0        1
```

*Edit: Removed a stray comma*

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a **base dataframe** `df` like this (doesn't need to have rows)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", 0, 0, 0, 1]], columns=["ID", "Fear", "Happy", "Angry", "Excited"])
```

```
  ID  Fear  Happy  Angry  Excited
0  A     0      0      0        1
```

and your **analysis data** are organized in another dataframe `data_df` like

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["B", "C"], "text_emotion": [["Happy"], ["Angry", "Fear"]]})
```

```
  ID   text_emotion
0  B        [Happy]
1  C  [Angry, Fear]
```

Then you could use [`.str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html): This

```
print(data_df["text_emotion"].str.join("|").str.get_dummies())
```

results in

```
   Angry  Fear  Happy
0      0     0      1
1      1     1      0
```

So when you concatenate this to `df`

```
df_new = pd.concat(
    [data_df["ID"], data_df["text_emotion"].str.join("|").str.get_dummies()], axis=1
)
df = pd.concat([df, df_new], ignore_index=True).fillna(0)
```

you'll get

```
  ID  Fear  Happy  Angry  Excited
0  A     0      0      0      1.0
1  B     0      1      0      0.0
2  C     1      0      1      0.0
```

The **columns are exactly like `df`'s columns**. To fix the float parts you could do

```
df[df.columns[1:]] = df[df.columns[1:]].astype("int")
```

and get

```
  ID  Fear  Happy  Angry  Excited
0  A     0      0      0        1
1  B     0      1      0        0
2  C     1      0      1        0
```